# Why can't compilers suggest const for me?

Tags: c++, g++, constants, compiler-warnings, clang++

Take the following snippets of code:

```
struct Foo{
  int _m=0;
  int Bar(){
    return _m;
  }
};
```

---

```
int Add(int x, int y){
  return x + y;
}
```

---

```
int main(){
  int i = 5;
  std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

During a code review, someone will inevitably bring up [const correctness](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness).
This results in the following revisions:

```
 struct Foo{
  int _m=0;
  int Bar() const{
    return _m;
  }
};
```

---

```
int Add(const int x, const int y){
  return x + y;
}
```

---

```
int main(){
  const int i = 5;
  std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

Surely a compiler could suggest that for me?
Looking at `clang` and `gcc`, I do not see any relevant flags.

Is there a reason compilers choose not to provide this?

Comment: You might love true functional languages where ALL variables are immutable.

Comment: `int Add(const int x, const int y)` and `const int i = 5;` are lame IMO.  Only marking the member function as `const` is important.

Comment: @SergeyA: They're not really "variables" then are they

Comment: @M.M: I couldn't disagree more.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I'm pretty sure you *could* disagree more (but yeah - const ftw!)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, i guess they are not. But how do you call them? Immutables? :)

Comment: @M.M, `const int i = 7` might (at least in theory) enable better optimizations for some compilers.

Comment: It is not so obvious to found where `const` can be added. As it can change semantic of code with overloads, SFINAE, ...

Comment: @SergeyA I doubt you could construct a test case for any real compiler (and if you can then perhaps report a bug... the same static analysis that would report a compilation error if the variable were const and potentially written to, will be able to let the compiler decide if the variable can be optimized the same way even when not marked `const`)

Comment: @M.M No this is the use case for `constexpr`. Healthy usage of `const` is obviously not quite as constrained as you can initialise at runtime, but making it _a compilation error_ to attempt modifying an invariant has obvious benefits and no downsides that I can see. Other than being "lame", whatever that means...

Comment: @MartinBonner: Nope, I couldn't!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `constexpr` on local variables is redundant.

Comment: @M.M. It most certainly is not.

Answer (score 1):

Because more often than not they'd probably get it wrong.

You could argue there to be benefit in doing so for *file-static classes* and *file-static functions*, because then all uses of those items are visible to the compiler in a single compilation unit (which is a prerequisite for this kind of thing). But how many of those do you have?

There is simply no benefit in spending the large amount of time it would take to program this ability into a compiler, for such minimal gain. Especially not when you already have code reviews to do it instead.

A professional static code analysis tool might have this feature, though. Shop around.

Comment: I do occasionally entertain the idea of a reversal semantics - everything is const unless declared `nonconst`.

Comment: @SergeyA: I very much wish the semantics of `const` and `mutable` were reversed.

Comment: As [tag:rust], which has `mut` for mutable (and things without `mut` is const) and suggest removal of unneeded `mut`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a reason compilers choose not to provide this?

Its partly historical(Though [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/) tries to [address this](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/2552cj/let_vs_let_mut_syntax_rather_verbose/) problem); and as to why it shouldn't be `const` by default: on a high-level, the compiler may have less idea of your intent than you think; (assuming, at the stage of parsing your file, it determines that you didn't modify the variables (i.e: it could be `const`): the issue of it enforcing `constness` would be largely gone at that stage). Of cause, those details `couldBeSafelyAssumedConst` may be helpful to the optimizer.

Consider:

```
int Add(const int x, const int y){
  return x + y;
}
```

and

```
int Add(int x, int y){
  return x + y;
}
```

There is a difference between the two (though not at codegen)... You could reassign the variables in the latter but not the former: see, the use of `const` is largely your duty, and specific to your intent/purpose/contracts etc...

---

Again, apart from providing more optimization opportunities, `const` largely prevents the programmer from accidental modifications. When the compiler generates native code, there isn't any notion of `const` correctness<sup>*</sup>:

Example: https://godbolt.org/g/Blpmpu ...(reproduced here):

```
struct Foo{
  int _m=0;
  int Bar(){
    return _m;
  }
};

int foo(const Foo& fg){
  Foo f(fg);
  int q = f.Bar() *4;
  return q;
}
```

The code generated for this is:

```
foo(Foo const&):
        movl    (%rdi), %eax
        sall    $2, %eax
        ret
```

As you can see, codegen *doesn't really* understand `const-correctness`. ***I think the compiler's job is to compile your code. Its your job (with the possible help of other tools) to write down your intent correctly (from all aspects).***

<sup>*</sup> Of cause, the `const` is very important in systems where you can mark memory locations as read-only.